# How to make the tooltip track mouse only horizontally using track:true?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am currently using jquery ui tooltip and using the `track:true` option. It works perfectly, however I dont want the tooltip to track the mouse when moving vertical  only horizontal

Any idea?.

```
 $(function () {
  $(document).tooltip({
      items: ".entry",
      position: {
          my: "right bottom+50"
      },
      track: true,
      content: function () {
              return "<div class='hi'>This is a very nice entry! It's    so pretty and I feel like I can touch it. This is just random filler text.</div>"; 
      }
  });})
```

Answer (score 4):

I added the `tooltipClass` property to the tooltip as follows:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    ...
    tooltipClass: "tooltip-position",
});
```

and added the following CSS to prevent the tooltip moving when scrolling vertically:

```
.tooltip-position {
    top: 200px !important;
}
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U6kKT/4/) for a Fiddle

Comment: Thanks! but what if I need to declare my position in order to implement the arrow functionality like in this example http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Comment: @user1163234 I think both will go without any conflict.